# How to execute sequential commands un linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I have what I guess is a pretty basic question about linux. Let us say I have I series of files, which run in couples. Each couple of files is the input of my command, which produces a single output. Then a would like to execute the same command with the following couple, producing a new output.

Let us say, for the example, that I have four files: `F1.R1, F1.R2, F2.R1, and F2.R2`

My first command would be:

```
myfunction F1.R1 F1.R2 -output F1
```

And the second:

```
myfunction F2.R1 F2.R2 -output F2
```

I would like to produce a command so that all couples are treated sequentially until all files are processed.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `.R1` files, replace `R1` with `R2` to get the other filename from the pair, then execute the command.

```
for file in *.R1
do
    file2=${file/.R1/.R2}
    output=${file%.R1}
    myfunction "$file" "$file2" --output "$output"
done
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, THANKS A LOT. It works for me. I had to tune it a little bit cause *. was giving me trouble, so that I had to use plain *, with no dot. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand that. If the filename is `F1.R1` it should be matched by `*.R1`. Do you have files like `F1R1` with no `.`?

Comment: Hi Barmar. I agree, and I did not go deeper into that, because it worked for me without the ".".  I will certainly be confronted to a similar situation soon enough, so I'll check it out then.